# How to add click & delete function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have the following code so the user can delete an uploaded image by pressing the `Delete` key, but what I want to do is make it so that whatever object the user clicks and then presses the `Delete` key is actually removed.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, removeImage);

function removeImage(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    var keyPressed = e.keyCode;
    if (keyPressed==Keyboard.DELETE)
    {
        imageLayer.removeChild(imageLoader);
    }
}
```

I want to do it so that if there is no `imageLoader` on the layer i.e. if an image hasn't been uploaded, the event listener will be removed, but will be added if a user clicks the 'Browse' button to upload an image again.

I'd like to be able to apply this to different objects (`Movieclips`) on different `Sprite` layers if at all possible.

I hope I have explained it well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an eventListener to each object that can be removed. When it's clicked, save that as the "activeObject", then in your remove metheod remove activeObject instead of imageLoader

Comment: So would I declare `activeObject` as a new movieclip and do it like that?

Comment: Yes, activeObject would have MovieClip type. It would never be a new movieclip though, assign it to the instance that was clicked. for example activeObject = MovieClip(event.target);